# How to install TikZ library in OSX to use in LaTeXiT?

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, mac, calligraphy, latexit

I am trying to use TikZ library in LaTeXiT, but can't find a way to install TikZ. Below is a screenshot from LaTeXiT.

[image]

Installed MacTeX and then tried to configure LaTeXiT to use pdflatex from texlive. But now I am getting more issues:

[image: i.imgur.com/lOYA4bG.png]

[image]

Comment: image posting is blocked for new users (until you get above a certain rep, 50 I think) I added the image for you,  welcome to the site!

Comment: What exact kind of LaTeX do you already have installed in order to use LaTeXit?

Comment: That library is part of the `spath3` package it appears (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3?lang=en), so use the TeX Live Manager (assuming you have MacTeX installed) to install `spath3`.

Comment: @daleif when I launched LaTeXiT, it asked for couple of modules, which I installed using homebrew.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Installing MacTeX now

Comment: Bad idea, use MacTeX, We have had several Mac users users lately that have had issues messing up MacTeX, texlive from mac ports etc. It is not worth it. use MacTeX. It is complete and super easy to install.

Comment: After installing MacTeX please remove the Homebrew version since there might be PATH interference between the two distributions.

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I have installed MacTex. What Preambles and settings should I do, to make LaTeXiT, use MacTex?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Added new screenshot, after installed MacTeX and configuring in LaTeXiT, I am getting more errors.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I checked the "which tex" and it is pointing to "/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdftex"

Comment: I know nothing about LaTeXiT, but an error saying that `\documentclass` is undefined typically occurs if you use `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex`.

Comment: Under the Typesetting Tab in the recent LaTeXiT 2.8.1 Preferences there is a small `Reset…` button that will allow LaTeXiT to reset the paths properly. With MacTeX/TeXLive 2015 and later there should be a path for pdflatex, xelatex and latex of /Library/TeX/texbin/... . Finally, did you just install the latest MacTeX? It looks like it's pointing to a 2015 version? Again, what OS version are you using?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks that helped in resolving the "\documentclass is undefined"

Comment: @HerbSchulz Thanks for the details, I am using OSX Sierra 10.12.6. I found that there were couple of packages in /Applications/TeX directory. 
I installed all of them and then launced LaTeXiT which was present in /Applications/TeX and then tested by including the tikzlibrary and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had to install MacTeX, which can be downloaded from http://www.tug.org/mactex/. Install all .pkg applications from Applications/TeX directory. It does contain LaTeXiT.

Overall on OSX, you just need MacTeX to get started.

[image] [image]